# How to create dynamic table using JPA 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0

I want to create a dynamic time table using pure JPA 2. Like in hibernate we create the dynamic table using SchemaExport.

The code:

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee;create=true"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
<properties>
```

The following exception occur when I use `create=true`:

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unknown database 'employee;create=true'
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: EmployeeService] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
```

Comment: id the JPA 2 implementation is hibernate based , in persistence.xml file we need to include the following property :     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `create=true` in `persistence.xml` url.

```
 <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     ...
    <properties>
      ---
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
          value="jdbc:???://localhost:port/DBName;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: with this the exception occur.